# Am I missing the preprocessing function in spaCy's lemmatization?

Tags: python, spacy, lemmatization

I'm trying to get lemmas (i.e. token.lemma_) for all tokens in a document using spacy.

**CODE:**

```
sentence = 'I'm looking for all of the lemmas. Please help me find them!'
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'NER])
doc = nlp(sentence)
tokens = [tokens.lemma_ for token in doc]
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

```
['look', 'lemma', 'help', 'find']
```

**ACTUAL RESULT:**

```
[-PRON-, 'be', 'look', 'all', 'of', 'the', 'lemma', '.', 'please', 'help', '-PRON-', 'find', '-PRON', '!']
```

Am I missing some sort of preprocessing function in spacy, or do I have to preprocess separately? I want all punctuation and stopwords to be removed ahead of lemmatization.

Comment: You may add a condition to exclude unwanted tokens

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov As a part of spaCy, or just as a conditional on the result?

Comment: The second option

Comment: You say you need to get *all tokens* lemmas, so why are you talking about filtering something out? Please clarify the question. Note `be` is a stop word, and will get filtered if you use `if token.is_stop`, but you want it to be present in the output. `[token.lemma_ for token in doc if not token.is_stop and not token.is_punct]` returns `['look', 'lemma', 'help', 'find']`. Please add more details to your question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't know that 'be' would be a stopword for this, as it's not in the NLTK stopword list. is_stop and is_punct are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
>>> [token.lemma_ for token in doc if not token.is_stop and not token.is_punct]
['look', 'lemma', 'help', 'find']
```

The following parts have been added:

- `if not token.is_stop` - if the token is a stopword
- `and` - and
- `not token.is_punct`  - if the token is punctuation, omit them.